# Add extra charges based on payment method in UberCart / Drupal?

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart

I know you can enable and disable payment methods using conditional actions, but I want to be able to add a fee of 5USD, if a person chooses the "Cash deposit" payment method. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Ubercart Payment Method Adjustments"-module seems to be what you are looking for:
http://drupal.org/project/uc_pma

I'm not sure if it works with your particular versions of Drupal / UberCart though.